# Securing a deployed Roo/GWT application

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, spring-roo

I recently succeded in uploading a Roo/GWT project on Google App Engine.
But, how can I secure it from the Google App Engine application dashboard?
Is there a way to tell to GAE to put a Google Login Box at the start and set a list of authorized accounts?

Thank you very much,

Regards.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Do you want to just add a login screen to access the application or do you want a more fine-grained approach (like, you can access the main page, but can't edit someone's profile)?

Comment: @Igo Klimer : I'd like to test both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answered ~same q. here [Adding an authentification system in a deployed Roo/Gwt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409481/adding-an-authentification-system-in-a-deployed-roo-gwt-project/3418007#3418007)

This is in progress to be implemented for GWT 2.1/Roo 1.1.0. See this for more details https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1003

If you can't wait, check the Spring Security in Google App Engine article, at http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/ That approach is not supported by Roo though (so once you change the generated code, it will be harder, but still possible, to continue using Roo)