# Adding an authentification system in a deployed Roo/Gwt project

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, spring-roo, federated-identity

I deployed recently a Roo/Gwt project on Google App Engine.

I spent a couple of hours but couldn't find a tutorial that shows, step by step, how can we add n authentification system (withe the Federated Login Api).

I found [this very good article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html) that provides some helpful code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OpenIdDemoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Map<String, String> openIdProviders;
    static {
        openIdProviders = new HashMap<String, String>();
        openIdProviders.put("Google", "google.com/accounts/o8/id");
        openIdProviders.put("Yahoo", "yahoo.com");
        openIdProviders.put("MySpace", "myspace.com");
        openIdProviders.put("AOL", "aol.com");
        openIdProviders.put("MyOpenId.com", "myopenid.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser(); // or req.getUserPrincipal()
        Set<String> attributes = new HashSet();

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        if (user != null) {
            out.println("Hello <i>" + user.getNickname() + "</i>!");
            out.println("[<a href=\""
                    + userService.createLogoutURL(req.getRequestURI())
                    + "\">sign out</a>]");
        } else {
            out.println("Hello world! Sign in at: ");
            for (String providerName : openIdProviders.keySet()) {
                String providerUrl = openIdProviders.get(providerName);
                String loginUrl = userService.createLoginURL(req
                        .getRequestURI(), null, providerUrl, attributes);
                out.println("[<a href=\"" + loginUrl + "\">" + providerName + "</a>] ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I setup this authentification module? Where should I put this code because there is no "main.java" file?

Thank you very much,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in progress to be implemented for GWT 2.1/Roo 1.1.0. See this for more details https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1003

If you can't wait, check the Spring Security in Google App Engine article, at http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/
That approach is not supported by Roo though (so once you change the generated code, it will be harder, but still possible, to continue using Roo)

Comment: So, there is no way to secure a deployed Roo/Gwt app?